# userForm disabling other workbooks

Tags: vba, userform

Does anyone know how to enable editing on other workbooks while UserForm is opened? Below makro that I've put into workbook

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     If Environ("USERNAME") <> "name.name" Then
     Worksheets("EQUIPMENT").Visible = xlVeryHidden
     Worksheets("EQUIPMENTFULL").Visible = xlVeryHidden
     Worksheets("SITES").Visible = xlVeryHidden
     Worksheets("EMPLOYEES").Visible = xlVeryHidden
     Worksheets("NEW").Visible = True
     Else: For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
      Worksheets(i).Visible = True
       Next i
  End If
  UserForm.Show
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can either make your form non modal or use a separate instance of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create modeless (as well as modal) dialog boxes. Modeless dialog boxes allow the user to continue to work in the application while the form is still displayed.

By default all userforms are displayed as *modal* which means that the user must close the userform before they can contine to use the application. When a UserForm is modal, the user must supply information or close the userform before using any other part of the application. No subsequent code is executed until the userform is hidden or unloaded.
Although other forms in the application are disabled when a userform is displayed, other applications are not.

When the UserForm is *modeless*, the user can view other forms or windows without closing the UserForm.

```
Userform1.Show ([modal])
```

with:

```
VBA.FormShowConstants.vbModal = 1
VBA.FormShowConstants.vbModeless = 0
```

(Taken verbatim from https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/modeless.htm)